# mix test does not insert data?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I wrote a test code for insertion schema.

```
defmodule DbServerWeb.GameSchemaTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true
  use DbServer.DataCase

  alias DbServer.Games
  alias DbServer.Schema.Game

  describe "insertion" do
    @valid_params %{game_name: "test_name"}
    @invalid_params %{game_name: nil}

    test "insertion with valid data" do
      assert {:ok, %Game{} = game} = Games.create_game(@valid_params)
      assert game.game_name == "test_name"
    end

    test "insertion with invalid data" do
      assert {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{}} = Games.create_game(@invalid_params)
    end
  end
end
```

then terminal outputs:

```
.....

Finished in 0.1 seconds
5 tests, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 820825
```

But there is nothing in my games table.

```
 id | game_name | inserted_at | updated_at 
----+-----------+-------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

Doesn't the test code insert data through schema?

Comment: The database adapter used in `:test` cleans the DB up between tests to prevent clashes and mess in general.

Comment: It helped me.
Thanks! <3

Comment: Also, the test database is different from the dev database or production database. Make sure you are checking the correct database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repo is set to Sandbox mode. This means that after transaction ends (wrapped unit test) it will rollback transaction for you. Often this configuration is in test.exs file but also can be set in `test/test_helper.exs`